# Is there a viable alternative to ImageCR3?

Tags: image, coldfusion

I rely on ImageCR3 for a number of my sites.  However, I've come up against a variety of limitations with it over the past couple years (single-threaded, no crop anchor, etc) and all of my emails to the support addresses have been ignored.  So I'm looking for an alternative.

My first thought was CFImage, but it seems to produce far too low of quality for the same image size, and seems excessively slow.  Is there any other tool out there that can do what ImageCR does, as efficiently as ImageCR does it, that I could use instead?  Or am I best off loading the jpg in CFImage, cropping and saving as PNG, then loading the PNG in ImageCR for the remainder of editing?

I'm using ColdFusion MX 7 and ColdFusion MX 9 (soon all to be migrated to the latter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick? Seems to work like a charm.

Comment: I decided to stick with ImageCR for thumbnails, and bring CFImage in for cropping during orders, for now.

But after review ImageMagick seems like the right choice for where I want to eventually be once load increases.  I also ran across cfx_OpenImage, which is based of IM, so I may go with that instead.

Thank you for getting me started along the right path.  :)